# Consuming Services In Angular5 is Not Working

Tags: angular, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

I am nearly new to angular and learning it from the Internet .

My App is at `Angular 5` and `.Net core 2.1`. I am trying to put some common method in a service instead of writing them again and again in every component

For example,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DropDown } from '../jlg/jlg-models/DropDown';
import { appConfig } from '../../_shared/app.config';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const httpOptions = appConfig.httpOptions;

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public DropDownList: DropDown[] = [];
  public PostOfficeList: DropDown[] = [];

  GetPostOfficeList() {
    this.http.get<DropDown[]>(appConfig.BaseUrl + 'api/Common/GetPostOfficeList/', httpOptions)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.PostOfficeList = result;
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
    return this.PostOfficeList;
  }   
}
```

And in my component I'm calling this like

1. Import Service

   import { CommonService } from '../../../../services/common.service';
2. Declare in the constructor

   private scv: CommonService

and also

```
PostOfficeList: DropDown[] = [];
```

Than inside Constructor

```
this.PostOfficeList = this.scv.GetPostOfficeList();
```

And in html

```
 <select name="POId" [(ngModel)]="PostOfficeId" class="form-control" required #POId="ngModel">
 <option *ngFor="let item of PostOfficeList" [value]="item.Value">{{item.Text}}</option>
 </select>
 <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="POId.invalid && (POId.dirty || POId.touched)">* Required Field </span>
```

The Code looks fine to me But it does not load data into PostOfficeList first time , when I switch to some other page and then come back to this page than I found it loaded into Dropdown

DropDown[] that I used in my `.ts` code is a class

```
export class DropDown {
public Text: string;
public value: string;
```

}

I debugged my API. It makes calls every time and return data even when angular not loading dropdown, so it seems like API is fine but the problem is on Angular

Below is the snapshot of `console.log()`

First time API return data, but it does print empty array.

Second time after switching page it print 3 items from the array which is correct.

[image]

How can I solve it?

Why it is not binding data to List first time?

Possibly angular is not waiting for API to return result on first time?

Comment: Try `this.scv.GetPostOfficeList().subscribe(s=>this.PostOfficeList = s)`

Comment: .subscribe () ?? in that case do I need to remove return statement from function inside service ???

Comment: And .subscribe is not available on  this.scv.GetPostOfficeList() here

Comment: change your `GetPostOfficeList() to return this.http.get...` and inside subscribe return `result`. Remove `return this.PostOfficeList;` Now subscribe will be available in component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.get` is async, so it takes time until the success callback, where you set `this.PostOfficeList = result`, is called. Call to http.get is not blocking, so when you return `this.PostOfficeList` in `GetPostOfficeList` it is undefined the first time. Eventually the data arrives and it is set in your service and available next time you call `GetPostOfficeList`.

Your service function should return `Observable` and you should subscribe to that observable in the components `ngOnInit` function. Or you can resolve the data in the router before your component is initialized.

Comment: Sounds logical , but what changes I need to do in my Service Function ?

Comment: @Jack you can read how to create http services in official tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6. What you need is to return `Observable` from your service.

Comment: I solved it by returning and observable and than subscribing it in my component

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how you can use `async` pipe work. Using this approach will defunately solvs your issue.

You can follow this example

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

---

Another way you can do this is like

```
<option *ngFor="let item of PostOfficeList" [value]="item.Value">


export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.GetPostOfficeList();
  }

  public DropDownList: DropDown[] = [];
  public PostOfficeList: DropDown[] = [];

  GetPostOfficeList() {
    this.http.get<DropDown[]>(appConfig.BaseUrl + 'api/Common/GetPostOfficeList/', httpOptions)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.PostOfficeList = result;
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }   
}
```

Comment: You suggesting [(ngModel)]="PostOfficeId | async" ?

Comment: No... I am suggesting to look async in this way.`*ngFor="let item in postofficelist | async"`. You have to make `postofficelist` variable observable which you get from the `http.get()`